# How to get ons-navigator to work with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, onsen-ui2

I am trying to build a simple list details app using **Vue.js** but I can't even get the fundamental page transitions to work. Here is what I have so far:

In **App.vue**:

```
<template id="app">
  <v-ons-navigator swipeable
    :page-stack="pageStack"
    @push-page="pageStack.push($event)"
  ></v-ons-navigator>
</template>

<template id="page1">
  <v-ons-page>
    <v-ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center">Page 1</div>
    </v-ons-toolbar>
    <p style="text-align: center">
      This is the first page
      <v-ons-button @click="push">Push Page 2</v-ons-button>
    </p>
  </v-ons-page>
</template>

<template id="page2">
  <v-ons-page>
    <v-ons-toolbar>
      <div class="left">
        <v-ons-back-button>Page 1</v-ons-back-button>
      </div>
      <div class="center">Page 2</div>
    </v-ons-toolbar>
    <p style="text-align: center">This is the second page</p>
  </v-ons-page>
</template>


<script>

const page2 = {
  key: 'page2',
  template: '#page2'
};

const page1 = {
  key: 'page1',
  template: '#page1',
  methods: {
    push() {
      this.$emit('push-page', page2);
    }
  }
};

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
  return {
       pageStack: [page1]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'
import App from './App.vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import axios from 'axios'
import vueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import VueOnsen from 'vue-onsenui'

import 'onsenui/css/onsenui.css';
import 'onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.css';

Vue.use(VueOnsen);
Vue.use(vueAxios, axios, VueOnsen);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
  data() {
    return {}
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

I'm getting this error:

> [Vue warn]: Injection "navigator" not found

I am trying to use the example provided here: https://onsen.io/v2/api/vue/v-ons-navigator.html

Comment: I don’t see it registered as a component.

Comment: Doesn't have to be registered as a component, at least that's what the docs indicate.

Comment: There is nothing obvious in the code you have here, and that error seems like it is likely specific to Onsen.  The error is getting generated by the code behind their navigator component template.  I would check for that sort of error on their website or in their debugging docs.  Sorry I can't help more